# How can I reboot or crash an iPhone in iOS 15 with an app

Tags: swift

I want to make an app that has a feature that reboots your device. I saw someone on Twitter do something like this and I want to know how I can crash/reboot and iPhone with a button.

Comment: Even if it were possible, what problem are you looking to solve by causing a user's device to reboot?

Comment: Any solution you find to this would be by exploiting an OS bug in a specific version of iOS. You should expect that bug to be fixed in a later release, "breaking" your app. There is no supported way to achieve this. The fact that someone shows a video of an iOS bug does not mean it's a feature of the OS. If you want to know what bug they exploited, and the specific version of the OS that it impacts, you should talk with whoever created the video.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the app crash (exit suddenly), but you cannot make the device reboot. The device belongs to the user. Think how dreadful life would be if such a thing were possible! If you saw an app that apparently made the device reboot, that was a jailbroken phone — or else the device was not actually rebooting.

Comment: I saw a video of a phone on iOS 15 and it rebooted without a jailbreak because iOS 15 cannot be jailbroken

Comment: The app won’t just suddenly reboot, the user will get an alert and choose ok to reboot

Comment: Understood, but the app has no power to make the device reboot, nor should it; so that doesn't change anything about my answer.

Comment: There are some exploits which can cause Springboard itself to crash, which turns the screen black and shows a spinning progress indicator while Springboard comes back up — this gives users the appearance that the phone is "rebooting", though it is doing no such thing. Inducing this on purpose is an absolutely terrible idea, and solves no perceived issues that one might ostensibly fix by truly rebooting the device.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Added some of that to my answer. :)